# Batch renaming of files with ascending number

Tags: shell-script, files, rename, mv

I have a batch of files:

```
$ ls
Li1Fe1O2_11 Li1Fe2O3_8  Li1Fe3O4_2  Li1Fe3O4_5  Li2Fe1O3_16 Li2Fe2O4_12 Li3Fe1O4_19 Li3Fe1O4_22
Li1Fe1O2_14 Li1Fe2O3_9  Li1Fe3O4_3  Li1Fe3O4_6  Li2Fe1O3_17 Li2Fe2O4_13 Li3Fe1O4_20
Li1Fe2O3_7  Li1Fe3O4_1  Li1Fe3O4_4  Li2Fe1O3_15 Li2Fe2O4_10 Li3Fe1O4_18 Li3Fe1O4_21
```

And I would like to rename them into:

```
enum-00132
enum-00133
enum-00134
...
```

I tried to look into rename without success.

Comment: How is the numbering of the final files connected to the original filenames? Are they just numbered serially?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
c=132
for f in *; do
  mv -v "$f" "enum-$(printf '%0*d' 5 $c)"
  c=$(($c+1))
done
```

The `c=<your_starting_number>`; I assumed `132` as in your question. Then the `for` loop runs trough all the files in the current directory. For every file the `mv` command is called. the `printf` utility prints the new filename with leading zeros. And finally the counter variable `$c` increments +1.

**Edit:** If you want only directories use this (`*/` machtes only directories, the rest stays the same):

```
c=132
for d in */ ; do
  mv -v "$d" "enum-$(printf '%0*d' 5 $c)"
  c=$(($c+1))
done
```

Comment: That's fantastic!!!!

Comment: one subtle question... So some of those are directories, however, if I want to change only the filenames of directory. What should I do ? Thank you.

Comment: @user40780 See my edit

Comment: `c=$((c=c+1))` is unnecessary.  All you need is `c=$((c+1))`.  In fact you can even just do `((c++))`.

Comment: @DigitalTrauma As specified in POSIX (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_04) this (`$((c=c+1))`) has the best portability

Comment: @chaos Point taken about `++` and `--` operators.  Still I don't get how `$((c=c+1))` is more portable than `c=$((c+1))`; `$(( ))` is by definition an expansion, so in the former case you'll need to do something with the value of the expansion (e.g. `c=$((c=c+1))`, or `: $((c=c+1))`).  In the latter case, `c=$((c+1))` assignment of `c` from the result of the expansion is all we need.  Or am I missing something?